# Why is "object.__dict__ is object.__dict__" False?

Tags: python

If I run the following code in a Python interpreter:

```
>>> object.__dict__ is object.__dict__
False
```

Why is the result `False`?

Comment: Because you get a `dict_proxy` object, which is created afresh each time you access the `__dict__` attribute and is read-only to try to prevent you from messing with `object`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`object.__dict__`, unlike other `__dict__`s, returns a `mappingproxy` object (a `dict_proxy` in Python 2). These are created *on the fly* when `__dict__` is requested. So as a result, you get a new proxy every time you access `object.__dict__`. They all proxy the same underlying object, but the proxy is a fresh one all the time. That’s why you can’t get two identical ones.

Comment: That being said, `{'foo':'bar'} is {'foo':'bar'}` appears to be `False`, too... isn't this a wider dict behavior, not something specific to `object.__dict__`?

Comment: Thanks, why this mappingproxy can not be cached and reuse then?

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn that's because you're creating *two separate dictionaries*. `d = {'foo': 'bar'}; d is d` will behave as you expect.

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn That’s because each dictionary literal creates a new dictionary.

Comment: @NathaneilCapital They could probably do that, but I assume that creating such a proxy is just a very cheap operation, as it just delegates the access to the underlying *real* dictionary. So just creating a new one is probably cheaper than creating and maintaining a cache.